# Returning tuple instead of integer

Tags: python-3.x

```
def max_product(nums):
    product = 1, 
    maxP = (min(nums))
    print(type(maxP))

    for n in nums:
        print(type(n))
        product *= n # here, product should be an integer but it is a tuple, don't know why 
        print(product)
        print(type(product))
        maxP = max(product, maxP)  # here, it is giving this error: 'TypeError: '>' not supported between  

                                     instances of 'int' and 'tuple''
        if n == 0:
            product = 1
        
    product = 1
    for n in nums[::-1]:
        product *= n # here also it is tuple
        maxP = max(product, maxP)
        if n == 0:
            product = 1
    
    return maxP


print(max_product([2, 3, -2, 4]))

# desired output: 6
```

I am trying to write a function in python that returns the maximum product of continuous elements in an array containing both positive and negative numbers. But the function is not returning the desired result. It is giving the error mentioned in the code. Please help me to find the error and solve the problem.

the type of 'product' should be integer, but it is of type 'tuple', as a result of that the 'max()' function is not able to work and giving the error.

Comment: I think that maybe you need to remove the comma `,` in the line: `product = 1,`, this makes the `product` variable of tuple type instead of int.

Comment: You are welcome, I think that this is a common mistake in Python. I will put this response as an answer, for you to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that maybe you need to remove the comma `,` in the line: `product = 1,`, this makes the `product` variable of tuple type instead of int.