# getting TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: typeerror, python-3.7

```
def c_convert(str_one, str_two):
    i=0,
    j=0
    while i < len(str_one) and j < len(str_two):
        if str_one[i].upper() == str_two[j]:
            j +=1
        i +=1
    return j == len(str_two)
def main():
    q = int(input())
    for _ in range(q):
        str_one = input().strip()
        str_two = input().strip()
        if c_convert(str_one, str_two):
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("No")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- I am getting error-TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' while executing the code , code is for comparing two strings.

I am getting runtime error.
input :
2
daBcd
ABC
rACCEd
ACED

Expected output:
YES
NO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921866/returning-tuple-instead-of-integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my mistake, As I am using 'comma' after a = 0 and it is interpreted as tupple.
after removing that my type error got fixed.
Thanks